# Docker: How do I debug localhost "Internal Server Error"?

Tags: python, docker, flask

First time using Docker(version 19.03.5) and trying this [tutorial](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/webapps.md#234-run-your-image) 
I'm stuck on step 2.3.4 Running an image
When I go to http://localhost:8888 I see 
`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

I updated `Dockerfile` to this to match my directory:

```
# our base image
FROM alpine:3.5

# Install python and pip
RUN apk add --update py2-pip

# install Python modules needed by the Python app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# copy files required for the app to run
COPY app.py .
COPY templates/index.html templates

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

On my command line I have 
`C:\Users\user\docker\flask-app>docker run  -p 8888:5000 --name flask-app 11111111/flask-app`
`* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
When I visit the page I see on the prompt
`172.17.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020 07:14:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

I have this in my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

# list of cat images
images = [
   "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26388-1381844103-11.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr01/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-31540-1381844535-8.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26390-1381844163-18.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-1376-1381846217-0.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-3391-1381844336-26.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-29111-1381845968-0.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-3409-1381844582-13.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr02/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-19667-1381844937-10.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr05/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-26358-1381845043-13.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-18774-1381844645-6.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr06/15/9/anigif_enhanced-buzz-25158-1381844793-0.gif",
    "http://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2013-10/enhanced/webdr03/15/10/anigif_enhanced-buzz-11980-1381846269-1.gif"
    ]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = random.choice(images)
    return render_template('index.html', url=url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

I can't figure out why my page isnt loading. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I have WAMP installed and this might be conflicting but not sure if thats the case and/or how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like your flask is running in the container, but when you visit (at localhost:8888) it returns a 500 error.  Hmm, seems like the error is correct - you likely have an error in your flask app.  Try replacing your flask app with a minimal one that you can see runs:  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application  If it runs ok, - the problem is in your app.  If it doesn't, you need to fix the docker container for the flask app

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler I added my app.py code to my post

Comment: At a Docker level everything should be working if you're getting a 500 error.  The application logs should have more detail (like a backtrace) explaining what's going wrong and you should look there.

Comment: @DavidMaze How do i get a backtrace? I've been trying to figure out how to debug this in Docker but havent been successful. I did install WAMP a couple of months ago on my machine so maybe theres come conflicts with that?

Comment: Try changing `COPY templates/index.html templates` to `COPY templates templates`. Flask might be unable to locate your templates

Comment: @abdusco wow! that did it! If you can answer ill give you the bounty

Comment: Actually, that's not an answer to your question, even though it solves your problem. Reminder: You asked how to debug something like this, not for a solution to your problem. For that, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask might be unable to locate your templates. Try changing

```
COPY templates/index.html templates
```

to

```
COPY templates templates
```

to copy everything inside `./templates` to `<WORKDIR>/templates`.

Using `COPY templates/index.html templates` will copy index.html as a **file** at path `<WORKDIR>/templates`, not copy it under that directory.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug your Flask application in Docker:

1. Turn on Flask debugger by adding `ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1` to your Dockerfile
2. Try to run the Flask app outside of Docker. It may be easier to set breakpoints inside your IDE (VSCode or PyCharm) and debug the app.
3. Try `pdb` to debug the app inside the container. It may be hard for a beginner, but in general, it's an essential skill. Check [Debugging a Python Flask Application in a Docker Container](https://dev.to/agiratech/debugging-python-code-running-in-docker-container-3b80) for a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is more aimed at the question "How do I debug". It was unclear that the OP actually wanted a solution, not a way to solve the problem.*

First thing to do is to start the container without the app in it. For that, you replace the `CMD ["python", "app.py"]` with `CMD ["sleep", "inf"]`. Now, after starting the container, you can get a shell in the container using `docker exec -it flask-app /bin/bash` to get a shell. In the shell, you can then use the regular Python debugger to set a breakpoint in the `/` handler and then single-step through the code to track down what Python's doing.